# Chrome is slow to load first AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, reactjs, flux

I am building an application using React and Flux. Clicking in a list of items initiates an action which then starts (via an effect) an AJAX request using `axios` (though I have tried `superagent-bluebird-promise` with the same results).

The issue is that using Google Chrome, when first making this request, there is a delay of approximately two seconds between clicking the item in the list and the AJAX request being initiated. Subsequent clicks instantly start loading the request.

Using Firefox, all requests are instantaneous.

Edit: I have tested on two Ubuntu PCs, and can replicate the same symptoms. I can also replicate the symptoms on my Android, with a bigger delay (about 4 seconds).

Here is a screenshot of a profile made under Chrome:

[image: Chrome weird dispatch action AJAX delay]

Is this a bug with Chrome, or what?

Comment: Maybe it's related to data caching at serverside and not chrome or android directly... Did you clear your firefox caches before measuring it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the server; the delay occurs before the AJAX request is initiated.

Comment: Well as the profile seems to indicate, there's a lot of stuff happening. You'd need to post some code for anyone to really give you a valuable answer.

Comment: There is too much code to put here. Essentially I've worked out that the larger the list of items, the longer Chrome delays. But Firefox never delays. Why could this be?

Comment: I have the same problem. First call In non-headless chrome it's fast, in headless it's slow. :-/ Did someone already open a bug ticket for that?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug with Chrome.

The project I'm writing has some code which is (more or less) directly copied from a previous (unfinished) project of mine.

Running the old project again, I encounter the same issue with Chrome. It never occurred before when I was working on it (a few months ago).

Comment: What's the bug? Is there a ticket?

Comment: Yes i also feel that