# Chrome requests taking much longer than other browser requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, vuejs2, axios

One of the users of my website noticed a severe delay in loading times for a infinite scroll function which makes a GET request to my API. While testing it, it only seems to happen in Chrome and Opera, the other browsers provide a near seamless experience.

So after some testing, I decided to do some time logging (sorry I can't post inline images on here due to too little reputation):
[image: Firefox time logs]

[image: Chrome time logs]
These logs are from the same calls, and as you can see chrome takes about 3000ms while firefox is around 90ms. IE/Edge have the same performance as Firefox.

To further the mystery, the network tab seems to report the ms correctly (around 100ms with some exceptions, but nowhere near 3000ms):
[image: chrome network tab]

Now for the actual code I'm calling:

```
loadMore() {
      console.time('start load');
     //some extra stuff here
        console.timeEnd('start load');
        console.time('state api call');
        this.$APIService.getCards(this.deckId, this.page, this.searchInput, this.lastId)
          .then(res => {
            console.timeEnd('actual call');
            console.timeEnd('state api call');
            //some more stuff here
    })
}
```

the "this.$APIService.getCards" call is just my apihandler:

```
getCards (deckId, page, searchInput,lastId) {
    console.time('actual call');
    return Api().get('cards?deckId=' + deckId + '&lastId='+lastId + '&search='+ searchInput)
  },
```

where "Api()" is my axios object:

```
 axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: baseURL
  })
```

Another thing to note is that my server only receives the request after the delay, so that would correspond with the network tabs stating it only takes around 100ms.

So, does anyone have any idea of why this might be happening? As you can see I literally have the time logs start right before the request and end them right upon receiving a result. Why would there be a delay before executing the call only in Chrome?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by checking if Disable Cache (Dev Tools -> Networking) is unchecked..

Comment: Disable cache was checked on both browsers. Meaning they would both do a non-cached request. I don't think it has anything to do with caching either since it actually has a delay before it sends the request on chrome and opera only.

I've found a thread from 2016 from someone with the same problem, but he wrote it off as a "chrome bug" in the end. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562083/chrome-is-slow-to-load-first-ajax-response )

Comment: Then analyze browser's timeline (Performance tab). You should see what happens within that 3s..